# Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$ contains all open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the collection $\mathcal{B}_0 = \{(-\infty, x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

**Exercise:** Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$ contains all open intervals, where $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{B}_0$.

**My solution:** Pick an arbitrary open interval $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. We know that $(a,b) \subset (-\infty, x)$, for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$ contains $\mathcal{B}_0$, $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$ contains $(a,b)$.

**Question:** Is my solution correct? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that intervals of type $(x,+\infty)$ also belong to $\sigma (\mathcal {B}_0)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sigma$-algebras are not closed under containment ($A \in \sigma$ and $B \subseteq A$ does not force $B \in \sigma$), so your solution is not correct. Instead, write
$$(a,b) = (-\infty,b) \cap (a,\infty),$$
where $$(a,\infty)^c = (-\infty,a] = \bigcap_{n \ge 1} (-\infty,a+1/n) \in \sigma(\mathcal{B}_0),$$ so taking complements gives $(a,\infty) \in \sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$. Since we have now written $(a,b)$ as an intersection of sets in $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$, this arbitrary open interval belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$. (I've used that sigma-algebras are closed under countable intersections twice in my answer.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do you know that $(-\infty, b) \in \sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$? Does $A \in B$ imply $A \in \sigma (B)$?

Comment: That's right, yes, because $\sigma(B)$ is defined to be the smallest sigma-algebra *containing* $B$.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. Yes, $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)\supset\mathcal{B}_0$. And, yes, $(-\infty,x)\in\mathcal{B}_0$. And, yes, $(a,b)\subset(-\infty,x)$. But how do you jump form this to $(a,b)\in\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$? If your argument was correct, it would follow from it that *every* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which has an upper bound belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_0)$, and this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty,a+\frac{1}{n}\right)^c=(a,\infty)$$